# Mitigating suspension and/or termination while encoding video in an app

Tags: c#, c++, windows-8, windows-runtime

I have a Windows Store app with an option to export certain data in a video file format. My app is in C#, but the encoding itself is handled by dropping into a C++ library adapted from  [this sample](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/eternalcoding/archive/2013/03/06/developing-a-winrt-component-to-create-a-video-file-using-media-foundation.aspx) by David Catuhe and is working well. The problem is that I have found is that the encoding process can take a long time when run at high quality, and if the screen times out (say, on a Surface RT) or the user switches apps, the process fails. I'm not entirely sure what the source of the failure is and am working to verify it, but even if the process were able to survive suspension without changes, I don't know how to handle being tombstoned.

I can live with the encoding being interrupted in certain situations. What I don't want is to have to start over from scratch if the app goes away for some reason.

As far as I can tell, it isn't feasible to simply close the stream without finalizing the video and resume writing to it later. In light of this, I have considered a few options, but I can't tell which, if any, might actually work. I'd be very grateful for some direction.

1) If possible, it'd be great to be able to simply close the stream and reopen it later, picking up where I left off. At the moment I haven't been able to get this to work, but if it SHOULD work I'd love to know.

2) Push the encode process to a background task, either from the start or only when tombstoned. But is there a way to pass an open stream from my app to a background task? If not, is there a way to get my app's background task to run without CPU/memory limitations at least while my app is in the foreground? Because doing a whole encode within the very tight constraints that normally bind background tasks would take years.

3) Render segments of the video progressively while the app is in the foreground and then stitch the parts together at the end. This way, if the encode is interrupted I can pick up at the most recent segment. From my reading this should be possible in theory (I think it falls under the category of remuxing, which would avoid the need to re-encode the video). But I haven't found any samples that cover this scenario, not even in C++ (which I have almost no experience with). The Transcode API doesn't seem to cover joining multiple samples. I've looked into using SharpDX to do it, but the most likely candidate for what I'd want to use (a Media Session) is only exposed for desktop apps.

4) Push the work off to either a desktop or server app. The problem is I want to have this run on Windows RT (so desktop is out) and I don't currently have a business model that can support servers capable of handling such intensive work on my customers' behalf.

So my question is, what is my best line of attack here? Is there any way to hold onto my stream across suspension? And if, as I suspect, option #3 is my best bet, do you know of any samples or guides on how to do it? Obviously C# options would be very much preferred, so I hope I am overlooking one. C++ might be OK (as it was with Mr. Catuhe's sample that got me this far), but I'm afraid I'd need some pretty specific guidance. The MSDN documentation on this, incidentally, is so high-level that I have only a vague idea of even which pieces I would need to assemble and what each requires, let alone how to write the actual program in C++.

Any help you could offer would be very much appreciated.

Comment: i'd suggest that #4 is the most appropriate choice for metro app. If you use backgrounduploader you will be able to push source to the cloud even if your app is suspended. You don't need to create your own server infrastructure for video encoding, since you can find existing cloud solutions.

Comment: Thanks @Denis. The content we are encoding is a combination of bitmaps and dynamically-generated vector information that might make finding a commodity solution that could work within the constraints of our economics difficult. I think we'd need to go with some general-purpose compute solution like Azure, but my sense is that that can get pricey. If we need to go this route, we probably will-- thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I don't have enough reputation points on SO to just comment so I have to give this as an answer.

You could consider a combination of #3 and #4. Render in segments within your app and then upload the segments for stitching together. This would bring you back into the realms of using a commodity solution to create your final output.